# startFabric.sh fails with docker compose command not find

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the tutorial on [writing your first application](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/write_first_app.html) to make a sample hyperledger fabric application. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed prerequisites as well as binaries and docker images. When I move into fabric-samples/fabcar, after npm install. I run:

```
./startFabric.sh
```

I get the following error:

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down.

./start.sh: line 13: docker-compose: command not found.

I looked into ./startFabric.sh by nano. Line 13 is as follows:

```
starttime=$(date +%s)
LANGUAGE=${1:-"golang"}
```

This is a screen shot of the error I get:

[image: ./starFabric.sh and ./startFabric.sh node are not starting my fabric]

It may be irrelevant, but I have also issues running .byfn -m up as I have posted on [issue with byfn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039938/hyperledger-fabric-byfn-m-up-doesnt-bring-the-network-up). I am not sure if these two are related. But obviously neither can I start fabric, nor can I build a network.

I appreciate any help to solve the issue.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install docker. If you already installed docker, you should check if your docker bin folder is referenced in your PATH environment variable.

https://docs.docker.com/install/

Comment: I have already installed docker and docker compose, just like as mentioned in prerequisites. Can you mention how I can check if it is added to the path? After it is installed isn't added to the path automatically?

Comment: I'm not an experimented ubuntu user, so I'm not sure it works but you should update your .bashrc in your home directory by adding the line: 
export PATH="/path/to/dir:$PATH". the path/to/dir is the "bin" path of your docker installation.

Comment: The problem was with docker-composer nopt being added to the path. After uninstalling, and a new clean isntallation it worked.